# How to find all "Name" parameters from big Json data using python3

Tags: python, json

How can I extract all the names from big JSON file using Python3.

```
with open('out.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Here I'm opening JSON file after that I tried this

```
a = json.dumps(data)
b= json.loads(a)
print (b)
```

Here is my data from JSON file.

```
{"data": [
{"errorCode":"E0000011","errorSummary":"Invalid token provided","errorLink":"E0000011","errorId":"oaeZ3PywqdMRWSQuA9_KML-ow","errorCauses":[]},
{"errorCode":"E0000011","errorSummary":"Invalid token provided","errorLink":"E0000011","errorId":"oaet_rFPO5bSkuEGKNI9a5vgQ","errorCauses":[]},
{"errorCode":"E0000011","errorSummary":"Invalid token provided","errorLink":"E0000011","errorId":"oaejsPt3fprRCOiYx-p7mbu5g","errorCauses":[]}]}
```

I need output like this

```
{"oaeZ3PywqdMRWSQuA9_KML-ow","oaet_rFPO5bSkuEGKNI9a5vgQ","oaejsPt3fprRCOiYx-p7mbu5g"}
```

I want all errorId.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
n = {b['name'] for b in data['movie']['people']['actors']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get or process the JSON data, you have to load the JSON first.

Here the example of the code

```
from json import loads
with open('out.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    load = loads(data)

    names = [i['name'] for i in data['movie']['people']['actors']]
```

or you can change `names = [i['name'] for i in data['movie']['people']['actors']]` to [Vikas P answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730875/11059811)

Answer (score 1):

Try using json module for the above.

```
import json
with open('path_to_file/data.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)

actor_names = { names['name'] for names in data['movie']['people']['actors'] }
```